# MediaPlayer Stop Button Crashes App

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've got a MediaPlayer which works fine and the stop button works okay. However if the user goes into the activity and presses the stop button without playing any music, the app crashes. If a song is played, the user can press the stop button as many times as they wish and it works fine. Any help would be awesome!

```
public class Website extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gridviewmusic);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    stopPlaying();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Website.this, R.raw.sound1);
                    mp.start();

                    // This will make  sound
                    break;
                case 1:
                    stopPlaying();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Website.this, R.raw.sound2);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    stopPlaying();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Website.this, R.raw.sound3);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    stopPlaying();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Website.this, R.raw.sound4);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    stopPlaying();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Website.this, R.raw.sound5);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/music/"));
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;

            }

        }
    });
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.pause();
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
        }
    });
}


private void stopPlaying() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(mp!= null)
    {
        mp.stop();
        mp=null;
    }
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            if(mp!= null)
            {
                mp.stop();
                mp=null;
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp!=null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
            mp.seekTo(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, it worked! Will mark your answer correct as soon as I can